# Using Android Nougat's shared memory for media decoding

Tags: android, memory, native, media, ashmem

I am porting my Android AOSP-based distribution from Android K to Android N. It includes a modified version of the Media Player that decodes DVD subtitles.
The architecture of the Media Player evolved a lot between those 2 versions. In particular, it is now split into 3 processes (see https://source.android.com/devices/media/framework-hardening).

I am thus trying to use Shared Memory to make the **MediaCodecService** send decoded bitmap subtitles to the **MediaServer**. I modified the contents of the structure that was previously created by **MediaCodecService** and added a **subtitle_fd** attribute, file descriptor to the decoded bitmap subtitle. When a message is received by the **MediaServer**'s **Nuplayer** for rendering, the code tries to map the aforementioned file descriptor.

Unfortunately, the result of the call to **::mmap** is always **MAP_FAILED**.

Do you have an idea of what I missed ?

- **Code of the MediaCodecService part**

  ```
  AVSubtitleRect *rect = sub->rects[0];
  size_t len = sizeof(*rect);
  int fd = ashmem_create_region("subtitle rect", len);
  ashmem_set_prot_region(fd, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
  void* ptr = ::mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
      ALOGI("%s[%d] dvb ptr == MAP_FAILED", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
  } else {
      ALOGI("Success creating FD with value %d", fd);
  }
  memcpy(ptr, rect, len);
  sub->subtitle_fd = fd;
  sub->subtitle_size = len;
  ```
- **Code of the MediaServer part**

  ```
  int fd = mSubtitle->subtitle_fd;
  size_t len = mSubtitle->subtitle_size;
  ALOGI("Trying to map shared memory with FD = %d", fd);
  void* ptr = ::mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
      ALOGI("Subtitle mmap ptr==MAP_FAILED %s", strerror(errno));
  } else {
      ALOGI("Subtitle get ptr %p", ptr);
  }
  AVSubtitleRect *rect = (AVSubtitleRect *)ptr;
  ```

Thank you so much !

Comment: Have you seen `ALOGI("Success creating FD with value %d", fd);`? Please add the `fd` to `ALOGI("Subtitle mmap ptr==MAP_FAILED %s", strerror(errno));`.

Comment: Yes I have seen the ALOGI in LogCat. It displays a positive value every time (between 19 and 45 in my tests). When I log the FD value in the second code snippet, it is always the same value as the one created in the first code snippet. Unfortunately, the ::mmap function called with this FD does not succeed.

Comment: Have you tried to disable SELinux (start Android in permissive mode)?

Comment: SELinux is disabled on my platform for now. `adb shell getenforce` returns **Permissive**. The same error happens whether SElinux is permissive or not.

Comment: Do you have any progress?

Comment: Nope, we finally chose another strategy :(